# theme style.css is not loading for custom theme

Tags: theming

I am trying to learn Drupal 8 theme development. I am trying to create basic theme
**My Folder structure**

```
|-themes
  |  |-custom
  |  |  |-contra
  |  |  |  |-css
  |  |  |  |  |-style.css
  |  |  |  |-contra.info.yml
  |  |  |  |-contra.libraries.yml
```

My contra.info.yml is as follows:

```
name: contra
description: 'Drupal 8 starter theme'
type: theme
core: 8.x
libraries:
   -'contra/global-styling'
```

My contra.libraries.yml is as follows:

```
global-styling:
version: 1.0
css:
    theme:
        css/style.css: {}
```

I have cleared the cache in Admin->Configuration->Development and also refreshed my browser but I dont see the style.css loaded in view source.

Comment: As shown, your .libraries.yml file has incorrect spacing. Does that reflect your file, or just the copy and paste?

Comment: yes that reflects my file. But I tried changing space. Where should I give space?

Comment: Looks like you may have 3 spaces when adding your library to your .info.yml file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your spacing. 2 spaces are required.

.info.yml:

```
name: contra
description: 'Drupal 8 starter theme'
type: theme
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - contra/global-styling
```

.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Also, take a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme